# Hlookup and Match equivalent in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

[sample.xls image](http://oi42.tinypic.com/r8azi1.jpg)

I have a code below, but it's not working properly. Something is missing in this code. Could you please help me with it?

Thanks in advance.

I added a sample.xls to show my request.

[sample.xls](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/afae454335bde14e3aa1205e6db8228120140104222844/3613ae56acfe92b53d15861a4284a7db20140104222844/0d6503)

i dont have an error handler, my function  with hlookup and match returns a value. but it returns with the same result (value) for each cell in `range(N6:CQ7899)`. normally if i use formula in cell `N6` `=IFERROR(HLOOKUP(N$5,min!$C$2:$CF$7899,MATCH($E6,min!$B$2:$B$7899,0),FALSE);0)` and go to last row and last col, each cell will have unique criteria with both `hlookup` and `match`. my request is how to do it by macro as follows; 
do for rows in ranges N6:N7899, O6:O7899, ... and CQ6:CQ7899

> N6
>   =IFERROR(HLOOKUP(**N$5**,min!$C$2:$CF$7899,MATCH(***$E6***,min!$B$2:$B$7899,0),FALSE);0)`,`
>   N7
>   =IFERROR(HLOOKUP(**N$5**,min!$C$2:$CF$7899,MATCH(***$E7***,min!$B$2:$B$7899,0),FALSE);0)`,.,.,.,.
>   up to last row.

and do for columns;

> `O6`
>   `=IFERROR(HLOOKUP(**O$5**,min!$C$2:$CF$7899,MATCH(***$E6***,min!$B$2:$B$7899,0),FALSE);0)`,
>   `O7`
>   `=IFERROR(HLOOKUP(**O$5**,min!$C$2:$CF$7899,MATCH(***$E7***,min!$B$2:$B$7899,0),FALSE);0)`.,.,.,.
>   up to last cell `(CQ7899)` in column `CQ`.

### if possible, please check sample.xls image or xls file.

```
Function matcd()

  Dim adegm As Range
  Dim adizm As Range
  Dim adegh As Range
  Dim adizh As Range
  Dim rnghFormulaCell As Range
  Dim varResult1 As Variant

  Set adegh = Worksheets("ara").Range("N5")
  Set adizh = Worksheets("min").Range("C2:CF7899")
  Set adegm = Worksheets("ara").Range("E5:E")
  Set adizm = Worksheets("min").Range("B2:B7899")
  Set rnghFormulaCell = Worksheets("ara").Range("N6:CQ7899") '

  Worksheets("ara").Range("N6:CQ" & Rows.Count).ClearContents

  varResult1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.HLookup(adegh, adizh, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(adegm, adizm, 0), 0)

  '.....

  'i don't know how to Add results of varResult1 to an array in rnghFormulaCell
  '.....

  If Not IsError(varResult1) Then rnghFormulaCell = varResult1

End Function
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Fair warning: we cannot diagnose your code without you showing us a minimal understanding of the code you are using as well as detailing the results you want. Besides, you have ***no*** question in your post. Kindly edit your post to be more clear as to what exactly are the errors being thrown--if any--as well as other diagnostic information about your code. We cannot use crystal balls, you know. ;)

Comment: Also, off a quick review of your coded: `adegm` is badly declared. `Range("E5:E")` needs to be checked, as it looks like a bad range (should it be something like "E5:E100", etc). Next is you're passing `adegm`, which is a `Range` type, to `WorksheetFunction.Match`'s first argument, which will throw an error since the first argument of `Match`, formula or VBA, does not take in a `Range`. ;)

Comment: did you check my sample xls file? i tried to explain my request in it.

Comment: yes your comment on the bad range is right. it was Range.("E5"). it is my mistake.

Comment: I have no way of checking your sample wb, but what dyou mean by not working properly? By looking at your code, it will work if `hlookup` and `match` function returns a value. Otherwise it will throw a `runtime error`. What you can do is to add an error handler.

Comment: thanks for your comments. i edited my question in detail.